# How can i change checkout,cart messages

Tags: magento-1.9, messages

How can i change checkout,cart messages?

Example

1:`Product Name was added to shopping cart I want cart to be replaced with bag.`

2.`Are you sure you want to remove item from shopping cart`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

**1.** Directly in the translation file -

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv.
```

**2.** If you activate inline translate in the admin panel -`> System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer -> Translate Inline -> Enabled for Frontend : Yes (don't forget to add your IP in Developer Client Restrictions -> Allowed IPs).`

Answer (score 1):

please check `Mage_Checkout.csv` line number 1 and 23 in `app/locale/en_US` folder.

%s denotes variable will append during execution time.

Change the column B text in `Mage_Checkout.csv` file as per your need.